# Access events added with attachEvent() / addEventListener() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events

How can I access events added with `attachEvent()` / `addEventListener()` in JavaScript?

Use case: debug events using FireBug's console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to access them.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, better way to debug the events might be to output the [event properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) you're interested in from the event handler function...

Answer (score 0):

If you always add and remove handlers with a custom method, you can maintain a log of them in the same method. It adds some overhead to do so.

For example, here is a piece that concerns IE-

```
//Run=window.Run || {Shadow:{},nextid:0};

else if(window.attachEvent){    
    Run.handler= function(who, what, fun){
        if(who.attachEvent){

            who.attachEvent('on'+what, fun);

            var hoo=who.id || who.tagName+(++Run.nextid);
            if(!Run.Shadow[hoo])Run.Shadow[hoo]={};
            if(!Run.Shadow[hoo][what])Run.Shadow[hoo][what]=[];
            Run.Shadow[hoo][what].push(fun);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of who.tagName+(++Run.nextid) line? Do actually use this log later on to release handlers?

Answer (score 0):

I know in jQuery (before version 1.8) you can do something like

```
$element.data('events')
```

And using fireQuery you can actually see the handlers in HTML tab [like this](http://gyazo.com/b7fdaae0832397940e124eb70784f048.png?1325854217)

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element)