# Displaying DOM element events and their handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inspect attached event handlers for any DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element)

Is there a tool - such as a browser extension, jQuery console script, bookmarklet or Firebug plugin - that displays all events that can be fired by a particular DOM element, and include any event handlers currently listening to those events?

Comment: Good call KennyTM - didn't spot that, however if possible I'd like to keep this open to see if there have been any new developments since that question was asked.

Comment: @ChrisFulstow Any new developments can go in the other thread perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for:

**FireQuery**

http://firequery.binaryage.com/

To do it your own, you can always access the `events data` structure from a `jQuery object`.

Example:

```
$(document.body).bind('click', function(){
   alert('I am an event handler!');
});

$.each($(document.body).data('events'), function(i,v){
  console.log(i);
  $.each(v, function(i2,v2){
    console.log(' > ', v2.handler.toString());
  });
});
```

That would list all events into your FireBug/Webkit console and print it's event handler functions as plain text. You can remove the `.toString()` part or just log `v2` the get more detailed information.

**update**

Like Anurag commented, that will show you only handlers which were bound through `jQuery`. It will not lookup up `addEventhandler() / addHandler` or inline-event handlers.

You can lookup inline-event handlers by checking for the `on-xxx` attribute. `DOM level3` does implement `hasEventListenerNS`, but I don't think any browser uses those yet.

Comment: You should add that this will only list events registered through jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's built-in developer bar shows event handlers bound to a particular DOM element, but it doesn't list events that don't have handlers already bound to them.

Comment: +1 - Also what do you mean by - "but it doesn't list events that don't have handlers already bound to them"? If an event, say - "keydown", has no handlers, then it won't be listed, which is rather obvious in any case.

Comment: @Anurag- I had the same thought, but the OP asked that it "displays all events that CAN be fired", which I assumed to be for reference purposes