# Loaded JavaScript files and dynamically events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Anyone knows a tool that collect all the js files that are loaded with a web page?

I know that Firebug through the script tab gives me all the js files downloaded with the web page, but I have to copy the URL from the tab and make the download one by one.

Another question, if I have one element in the web page, for example:

```
<a href="#" id="test1" ...>
```

How can I know all the events associated with this element? Events that were add dynamically for example in the `onsubmit` event through JavaScript, for example.

```
document.getElementById("test1").onclick = "function()...."
```

Comment: For your second question have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Question:** Chrome's inspector tool

**Second Question:** refer to this post: [Inspect attached event handlers for any DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element)