# Should $("#elementid").click(...) show in DOM?

Tags: jquery, firebug

If I attach to onclick in an anchor tag for example, should I be able to see this in Firebug after the DOM has loaded?

The onclick is not firing and I'm trying to figure out what is wrong.

```
$("#myelementid").click(function() {
    alert('test'); 
    return false;
});
```

I've also tried .onclick(...)

Comment: Missing document ready handler? jQuery doesn't add `onclick` attribute to the elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element

Comment: This is inside another block of jQuery that is already firing.  Document ready isn't needed here.

Comment: Which block? Do you generate the element dynamically? http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: Why not provide us with a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or more code to clarify your problem?

Comment: Because it is buried inside of other code.  Any way, this doesn't have anything to do with the OP.

Comment: @undefined How do you add an onclick attribute to an anchor tag via jQuery than?

Comment: @4thSpace I don't do that, I use `click` method as you have used. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: @undefined I don't think $(element).on(...) from that example is valid.

Comment: ok, that's what I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yUTVe/

I think you'll have to dig a little deeper, as you could have open brackets somewhere.  Your code is completely fine, so unless you are dynamically creating that element (and thus, the JQuery doesn't work for it), there must be a syntax error somewhere else.

```
$("#myelementid").click(function() {
alert('test'); 
return false;
});
```

Comment: I guess something is conflicting somewhere.  To answer my OP, I checked your code on jsfiddle.  The onclick doesn't show up in the DOM.

Comment: Not sure why stackoverflow doesn't let you me up vote your answer.  Says I can't vote for my own post.

Comment: No worries, hope you find what's causing your issue.  Good luck.