# find event handlers selenium webdrive

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, event-handling

I just started using Selenium.

Is it possible to find event handlers attached to an HTML element by selenium?
The handler (for example handler for onclick of a button) may be attached on-the-fly by addEventListener.

Comment: posible this link could be usefull to you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element

Comment: Thanks Archana. One interestin tool mentioned in that link is Visual Event tool (http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) which we consider using :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we did it. We used Selenuim + PhantomJS. Using phantom, we get then DOM of the page, inject and execute visual event parsers on the page, store events list on the page and return them by another javascript call through phantom.