# JS: Retrieve events bound to element

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I've got a page with different javascript framework, and I need to retrieve all the events defined.
So I'm looping through the DOM elements in order to check which one has at least one event.

Is it possible to retrieve all the events bound to a certain element in pure javascript (not using any framework) regardless the way used to bind the event to the element?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element)

Comment: I've found the solution and I've created this gist https://gist.github.com/fabiocicerchia/7116129, it'll extend the event listener in order to catch all the possible events.