# View DOM level 2 Event handlers in IE

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, events, dom-events

Is there any way to view [DOM level 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#DOM_Level_2) event listeners added to a DOM element in IE 9+?

In Chrome, we can see attached events from console using [getEventListeners(object)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#geteventlistenersobject).

I tried [Visual Events](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2), but it only displays DOM level 0 events.

In case if you are wondering, I need to list the attached event handlers to window unload event and debug which events are fired to find out which one is causing an exception/preventing propagation. The unload event handler is getting dispatched properly in Chrome.

Comment: [have a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can easily see DOM2 handlers:

- Right-click the element with the event handler and choose Inspect Element
- That should trigger the DOM Explorer tab; if not, do so
- Pick the Events tab on the right-hand side

It lists the event handlers attached to the element, including DOM2 ones.

For instance, using [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcpv5Ldx/1/):

```
<div id="target">
I have a DOM2 event handler.
</div>

function thisIsADOM2Handler() {
    this.style.color = "green";
}
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("click", thisIsADOM2Handler, false);
```

I followed the steps above to see this:

[image]

> I need to list the attached event handlers to window unload event

You'll find the handlers for the `window` `unload` event listed on the `body` element, so navigate there in the DOM Inspector to see them:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That works for DOM elements. Is there any way to view window.unload handlers?

Comment: @SenJacob: Those show up on the `body` element; I've updated above.