# How do I get the real button click processing html/javascript code by only having its class name?

Tags: javascript

Traditionally, to respond an button click event, we could use some code like this

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Nowadays button click processing seems to use some kind of link/observer. This is "Add Question" button from Quora.

[image]

Here is part of its HTML

```
<div class="q-click-wrapper qu-active--textDecoration--none qu-focus--textDecoration--none base___StyledClickWrapper-lx6eke-1 lokDfm puppeteer_test_add_question_button  qu-ml--small qu-borderRadius--pill qu-alignItems--center qu-justifyContent--center qu-whiteSpace--nowrap qu-userSelect--none qu-display--inline-flex qu-bg--red qu-tapHighlight--white qu-textAlign--center qu-cursor--pointer qu-hover--textDecoration--none" type="button" tabindex="0" role="button" style="box-sizing: border-box; direction: ltr; font: inherit; outline: none; padding: 5px 15px; max-width: 100%; border-width: 0px; color: inherit;">
```

I guess the key is `puppeteer_test_add_question_button`, how do I get the real button click processing html/javascript code?

Comment: setonclicklistener on that button would help

Comment: What do you mean by "real button click processing"? Are you asking how to add an onclick event to the button without using the `onclick` attribute? If so, you can use `addEvenetListener()`, with a method such as `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelector`

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you. I don't know how quora implement that button-click-processing and I'm trying to figure it out. I searched "onclick" in its HTML but get nothing. I don't know what else I could try.

Comment: The previous comments are pointing towards setting up new event listeners. I understand OP's question in the sense of  "sniffing out already attached handlers". Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a script way if doing it. But maybe the following answer is helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element ?

Answer (score 0):

Write a querySelector to get that Element. For example:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button.bla.bla")
```

Then add click event listener on the Element like,

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log('clicked')
}
```

And if you want to click it from javascript,
just do this,

```
button.click()
```

Now your question is, it already does something, and you want to find the code and figure out which javascript function is being called.
For that, look for **sources** in chrome debugger tools, and you will see javascript files, observe them. You will find the code somewhere. You can set breakpoints to test when event is fired.