# Is there a JavaScript call to retrieve a list of events attached to a specified DOM element?

Tags: javascript, events

Is there a JavaScript call to get the list of attached events from specified DOM element?

Comment: Already asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681120/access-events-added-with-attachevent-addeventlistener-in-javascript (And the answer is no, no such call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to do some debugging, the [Eventbug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug) Firebug extention might be of use.