# Check if an element has event listener on it. No jQuery

Tags: javascript

How to check if an element has event listener on it, if I use an inline function on it like the code below? Because I have a function that recalls the function and add the event listener, but it cause to have duplication event listener causing it to trigger a function twice. How can I check it so I can prevent it to add an event listener if is it already exist?

```
for (var a = 0;a<formFieldInput.length;a++) {
    if(formFieldInput[a].hasAttribute("name") && formFieldInput[a].attributes.title.value !== "Valid Until") {
        formFieldInput[a].addEventListener("click",function(event) {
            toggleFieldList(event,"show");
        });
    }
```

Comment: you can remove it before you add it

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add the listener and an additional property, like `data-listener = true`, then check if `data-litener` is set and only add the listener if not?

Comment: you can also use direct assignment to bind one-per-event handlers, ex:  formFieldInput[a].onclick=function(){...}; when you replace those, the old one just goes away without complication...

Comment: @pawel thanks. it works. i add a addition attribute on it. 

formFieldInput[a].setAttribute("events",true); 

i will do now is to check if hasAttribute("events") to do the checking :D

Comment: Not sure if it's a good practice, but I solved my issue of having duplicate events by removing the all sibling events (in my case) at the beginning of the event function. I used the off() jQuery function http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 114, accepted):

There is no JavaScript function to achieve this. However, you could set a boolean value to `true` when you add the listener, and `false` when you remove it. Then check against this boolean before potentially adding a duplicate event listener.

Possible duplicate: [How to check whether dynamically attached event listener exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455515/how-to-check-whether-dynamically-attached-event-listener-exists-or-not)

Comment: it's so weird javascript doesn't tell you that! I find this so odd.

Comment: @vsync
It's not a JavaScript issue, it's a browser feature and how they manage the DOM.
If Browsers were to handle such a check, it would probably be similar to what Ryan Warner said.

Comment: @SebastienDaniel - yeah this what I meant, the DOM..

Comment: Simple and efficient, thanks i was stuck with anonymous function that cannot be detached, and cannot be cloned cause another event was listening on node changes...

Comment: @yeah flag is prefect! event duplication bind bug & h5 dataset flag solution
https://codepen.io/xgqfrms/full/PaRBEy/

Comment: @ryan-warner code examples help as well when posting answers...

Answer (score 118):

Since 2016 in Chrome Dev Tools console, you can quickly execute this function below to show all event listeners that have been attached to an element.

```
getEventListeners(document.querySelector('your-element-selector'));
```

**Disclaimer**: This solution is only works for **Chrome** developer tools.

Comment: is this solution cross browser or just chrome??

Comment: @Anthony as I mentioned above, it only works on Chrome Dev Tools

Comment: Quick way in jQuery: getEventListeners($('your-element-selector')[0]); will list also the array with the events of the element in the dev tools.

Comment: This does not work in Firefox

Answer (score 101):

You don't need to. Just slap it on there as many times as you want and as often as you want. [MDN explains identical event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners):

> If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same
> EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are
> discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and
> they do not need to be removed manually with the `removeEventListener`
> method.
>
> Note, however that **when using an anonymous function** as the handler, such listeners will NOT be identical, because anonymous functions are not identical even if defined using the SAME unchanging source-code called repeatedly, even if in a loop.

Comment: This may be true for equivalent function _references_, but not identical functions. `addEventListener(function() { alert('x'); }); addEventListener(function() { alert('x'); });` will alert `x` twice.

Comment: THis was the right answer for me. I needed to know if the event was added to stop it from being added again. By making it a named function the rule above applies and the listener is not added.

Comment: it's important to note as @CharlesStover mentioned, the above article also states: Note, however that when using an anonymous function as the handler, such listeners will NOT be identical, because anonymous functions are not identical even if defined using the SAME unchanging source-code simply called repeatedly, even if in a loop.
This explained the behavior I was seeing.

Comment: Note: this will not work if you use .bind() on the *named* function in addEventListener

Comment: Same as @Charles Stover I still get event twice!

Comment: @RonnieRoyston please rewrite your answer so that it warns instead of encouraging, taking note of Charles' and David's comments, because people are likely to not know about these, and probably won't read the fine print, resulting in low-quality code

Comment: This will not work if for example you have a class or a constructor function from which you create some DOM element on which you attach a listener, then from within this execution context you call the constructor to create a new instance and a new execution context that runs inside the first. Then if you do some DOM query from this context-within-context to attach the same named function as a handler to that DOM element from the first containing context, that 'above' context will not be able to tell you're adding the same handler. It will add a new listener, the same. So you end up with clones