# Openlayers: determine if precompose handler was set

Tags: openlayers

I need to determine if a precompose-callback was set on a layer:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  renderMode: "image"
});
```

and sometime later I add a precompose handler.

```
layer.on("precompose", function(event) {
  //Some clipping is applied here
});
```

How can I determine, if a layer has a precompose-handler (e.g., `layer.has("precompose")`)?

I am using Openlayers 5.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a state manually on your layer to find yourself if you already set an event like "precompose". This behaviour is similar to JavaScript `addEventListener` except your are using OpenLayers layer instead of DOM element (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056716/check-if-an-element-has-event-listener-on-it-no-jquery/41137585))

```
layer.on("precompose", function(event) {
  //Some clipping is applied here
});
layer.set('withPreCompose', true);
```

Then you can get layers with precompose event

```
map.getLayers().getArray()
  .find(el => el.get('withPreCompose'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I need some time to think about this... It feels ulgy to manually handle the state.