# Angular 2+ detect within a component if a click listener is assigned

Tags: angular

I am creating a reusable component which is showing a rounded image thumbnail as content. I want to detect within this component if a developer has assigned a click listener to it and modify the style and behaviour of it slightly. Basically add a `cursor: pointer` style if a developer assigned a `(click)=anyClickCallbackFunction()` on the component.

The question is, how can i read this from within the component?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056716/check-if-an-element-has-event-listener-on-it-no-jquery

Comment: One simple approach would be to pass a boolean prop from the parent to determine whether the child comp has a click event or not: 
`<child-comp [hasClickEvent]="true" (click)="clickCbFn()"></child-comp>`

Comment: Thanks, so it seems it's not possible, yes passing in a boolean is an option, but this is not ideal, as its error prone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for doing that you need to have `click` output in your component although you are not using it, then check how many `observers` exists

```
export class MycompComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() click : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  hasHandler : boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hasHandler = this.click.observers.length > 0;
  }

}
```

see working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-check-event-handler-exists)

Comment: I am having some more difficulties with this. I am trying to listen for the click event in the component as well by adding a @HostListener('click'). In this case the observers.lenght is always 1, regardless if i add a (click)="onClick()" on the component. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @DArkO can you fork my stackblitz and modify it to show your issue

Comment: Here it is demoing the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-check-event-handler-exists-r7xzbd

Comment: check this workaround https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-check-event-handler-exists-cm1tk4

Comment: @DArkO btw I found out we should check number of subscribers in observers (not the observers), btw that one is always 1

Comment: I was thinking the same thing when i found the issue, but i was inspecting the event emitter and i couldn't find any point where the 2 subscriptions are registered.