# Check with javascript if event handler was added to attribute

Tags: javascript, crm

Hi working with CRM Dynamics 2015 and i want to check in my javascript code if event handler was already added before I add it once more
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check whether dynamically attached event listener exists or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455515/how-to-check-whether-dynamically-attached-event-listener-exists-or-not)

Comment: I not working with regular document element, I am use Xrm that exist in SDK

Comment: Just curious - how could that be that your application doesn't know has event handler attached already or not?

Comment: I run script that add event handler to element when other element's value was changed, in case if value changed once then handler was added and no need to add it again

Answer (score -1):

You can get a list of events currently assigned to an element by using the following JQuery code.

```
$._data( $('.element')[0], 'events' );
```

If element has no events, it returns "undefined"

**Edit:**

If you're looking for native solutions see this link
[How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

Comment: As a side note, author did not specify whether he is using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you I added a reference for native solutions