# How to get hold of event binding attribute in Angular2 like (click) or (keyup) and insert them in new html element

Tags: angular, typescript, polymer, web-component

My custom Polymer webcomponents malfunction with Angular2. I had to wrap them in custom directive (which delays the rendering of web components until the are inserted into the DOM by angular).

Wrapping works like that:

```
<my-custom-wrapper component="custom-fancy-element"></my-custom-wrapper>
```

What basically happens is that directive `<my-custom-wrapper>` is being hidden and I insert the `<custom-fancy-element>` before this hidden element. `<custom-fancy-element>` is correctly shown on the web page. The problem is when I want to apply event binding attribute like `(click)="someFunction()"`.

This is what I do:

```
<my-custom-wrapper component="custom-fancy-element" (click)="someFunction()">
</my-custom-wrapper>
```

And this is what I want as a result:

```
<custom-fancy-element (click)="someFunction()"></custom-fancy-element>
```

**How is it possible to fetch this event binding attribute from inside TypeScript and later on add it to the newly created html element?** I tried `.setAttribute("on-click", "someFunction($event)");` but angular doesn't recognize it.

Below is a code snippet of how I handle other attributes (like value="something" class="alert green-stuff" that I want to be added to the newly created HTML element.

```
constructor(@Attribute('component') component: string, element: ElementRef) {
  this.component = component;
  this.element = element;

  var my_new_component = document.createElement(this.component);
  if (my_new_component.constructor !== HTMLUnknownElement) {
    if (this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute("value")){
      my_new_component.setAttribute("value", this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute("value"));
    }
    if (this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute("class")) {
      var myComponentClasses = this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute("class").split(" ");
      for (var i = 0; i < myComponentClasses.length; i++) {
        my_new_component.className += " " + myComponentClasses[i];
      }
    }
    this.webcomponent = my_new_component; // Which is just:
               // <custom-fancy-element class="blue-pattern" value="some"></custom-fancy-element>
}
```

}

And later on I insert HTML element before my directive like that:

```
ngOnInit() {
  var parentNode = Polymer.dom(this.element.nativeElement).parentNode;
  if (parentNode) {
    Polymer.dom(parentNode).insertBefore(this.webcomponent, this.element.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

I guess, getting and setting attribute in Angular 1 would be possible with

```
.directive('someDirective', function() {
   return {
     ...
     link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
       //assign attribute to web component
     }
}
```

but how to do it in Angular2 and TypeScript?

Comment: Why not add it as part of your component, but hidden with a conditional?
`<custom-fancy-element *ngIf="someValue === true" />
    
    <my-custom-wrapper (click)="thisSetsAValueToMakeCustomFancyElemShow()">
    </my-custom-wrapper>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported. You can't add `(click)` or `(keyup)` dynamically to the DOM. You can get hold of an element and use `addEventListener(...)`

Angular2 binding syntax only works when statically added to a components template.

Comment: The problem is, how do I check if `<my-custom-wrapper>` directive has an event binding attribute like `(click)="someFunction()"` so I could add event listener for click to corresponding <custom-fancy-element> webcomponent?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question. `(click)="someFunction()"` is some declarative binding that gets removed when Angular compiles the template (offline template compiler or at runtime when it creates the component) and replaces it by `addEventListener('click', ...)`. When the component exists in the DOM there won't by any `(click)="..."` anymore.

Comment: I don't really want to check for "physical" existance of `(click)="someFunction()"` between some html tags. I want to check if there is an event attached to it, like (click) or (keyup). Is it possible?

Comment: I guess not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455515/how-to-check-whether-dynamically-attached-event-listener-exists-or-not