# How can I tell if a website is capturing my mouse movements?

Tags: javascript, mouse

I'm talking about whether I move a mouse at all without clicking. Can a website detect that and capture it? Is there a way in the console or using a program?

Also, is it possible to capture mouse movements server side?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether dynamically attached event listener exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455515/how-to-check-whether-dynamically-attached-event-listener-exists-or-not)

Comment: Yes, both those things are possible with JS.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect and capture mouse move on clientSide and there is possibility to send that coordinates of mouse from client side to server side ie. every 10 ms.

```
$( "div" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  var pageCoords = "( " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + " )";
  var clientCoords = "( " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY + " )";
  $( "span:first" ).text( "( event.pageX, event.pageY ) : " + pageCoords );
  $( "span:last" ).text( "( event.clientX, event.clientY ) : " + clientCoords );
});
```

Working example
[Example on JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/gmftbas9/)

Comment: Hey, I'm not the one trying to detect mouse movements. I'm trying to see if a website is detecting me.