# Angular. Bind event only one time (on first init)

Tags: angular, addeventlistener, ngoninit

Let say I want to alert user every time he clicks on `<a>` tag.

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (event : any) {
            if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('Congratulations! A tag clicked!!!');
            }
        });
```

If I put this binding in `constructor` (on in `ngOnInit()`) I will have new binding (and one more alert) every time i go to this component (router link).
What is the way to bind only one time, on the first init?

In the meantime I use `removeEventListener()` in `ngOnDestroy()`. It seems to be ugly. Is there anything better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to check whether the desired event listener already exists on your element or not. Please refer to: [How to check whether dynamically attached event listener exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455515/how-to-check-whether-dynamically-attached-event-listener-exists-or-not)

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47330239/8151732) I would advise to use something like this (works for me at least):

```
function showAlert(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert('Congratulations! A tag clicked!!');
}

  const aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  for (const i in aTags) {
    const element = aTags[i];
      if (element instanceof Element && element.getAttribute('listener') !== 'true') {
        element.addEventListener('click', showAlert);
        element.setAttribute('listener', 'true');
    }
  }
```

If you need to bind your event listener to the whole body like in your example, you may use a static variable. Just create one at the beginning of your component and check it's value before binding an event listener. E.g.:

```
export class CongratulationsComponent implements OnInit {
  static flag = true;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (CongratulationsComponent.flag) {
      document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (event: any) {
        if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
          event.preventDefault();
          alert('Congratulations! A tag clicked!!!');
        }
      });
      CongratulationsComponent.flag = false;
    }
  }
}
```