# Prevent listener from being added if it already exists

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to prevent my GMaps object from adding unneeded listeners.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapWrapperElem, mapOptions);
map.addListener("click",function(event){
    // Do stuff
});
```

How do I prevent `map` from adding a "click" listener if there's already a "click" listener on it?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to check whether dynamically attached event listener exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47414605/7138697)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be achieved. There is not way to detect if there is an event listener added or not.

There is a rather complex method of doing it:

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47414605/7138697