# Assign results for console.dir

Tags: javascript, return, console.dir

Is there a way to read/assign the results of console.dir(object) into a variable for processing in my own javascript code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, that's a security risk (console ignores some restrictions), so there's no way to reach such results.

Comment: i see.. thanks. is there a javascript function/library equipvalent for console.dir? that can do what I want?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you can use a template to turn Object.entries(obj) into interactive HTML

Comment: trying to create a simple intellisense editor and a watch variables console in my html page

Comment: thanks dandavis.. tried using Object.entries(obj) on a DOM label object.. but can't get list of events associated with it. (eg. onclick, ondblclick, etc..)

Comment: Sounds not exactly like, but similar enough to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455515/how-to-check-whether-dynamically-attached-event-listener-exists-or-not

Comment: yeah, events are not iterable afaik, given an elm; you'd have to mod the subscriber mechanism (ex addEventListener) to log each binding, and even then, you won't catch delegated events without great effort