# removeEventListener without reference to event handler

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I want to know if it is possible to remove an event listener without a reference to the event handler function that should be removed.

Jquery's `$().unbind('touchmove')` will not work because the event listener was added using Javascript's `addEventListener('touchmove', handlerFunction)`, not Jquery's `bind` function.

`removeEventListener('touchmove')` does not seem to work, which is consistent with the Javascript function spec.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825493/removeeventlistener-is-not-working Check the last answer, that maybe helps you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296858/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-event-listener-bindings-in-javascript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qUtzL/4/ could this be your problem??

Answer (score 0):

You can get all event listeners for a DOM element and remove one/all:

```
var eventlistener = getEventListeners(window)["DOMContentLoaded"][index];
window.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", eventlistener.listener, eventlistener.useCapture);
```

Taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26845805/712700

Answer (score -2):

You should always add events to a specific object so you can access them later, try this.

to add:

```
window.addEventHandler( 'touchmove', function );
```

to remove:

```
window.removeEventListener( 'touchmove', function );
```