# Is there a way to check if a message event listener already exists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, browser, next.js

Is there a way to check if a message event listener already exists?

I want to do something like:

```
if(noMessageEventListenerExists) {
  globalThis.addEventListener('message', async function (data) {})
}
```

I saw that working for onClick events but then you have to specify the id of the Element you want to check.

Is there a way to do that for 'message' event listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save a reference to the event listener while creating, like this:

```js
if(!globalThis.onmessage) {
   globalThis.onmessage = globalThis.addEventListener('message', async function (data) {})
}
```

Otherwise its (probably) lost and you can't find the event listener anymore. Some browsers seem to have (had) a getEventListeners() function, but this seems like nothing that you should rely on.

See more here: [removeEventListener without knowing the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845535/removeeventlistener-without-knowing-the-function/26845805#26845805)