# Reinitialise array of click events for links after page has dynamically changed

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, onclicklistener

I am trying to make a simple site and convert it to an SPA using vanilla javascript.

I want to target all of my hyperlinks which start with an `'/'` as these are internal to my site.

Works fine for pages loaded in the DOM initially from the server. But if I dynamically add more links to the page that contain the same property I need a way to recalculate my list of internal links. This is a simplified version of a slightly more complex iteration.

Snippet below, but I also made a codepen: https://codepen.io/lharby/pen/OJqoRpx

```js
  const trigger = document.querySelector(".add-template");
  const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
  const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  const internal = [...links]?.filter((item) => item.getAttribute("href")?.startsWith("/"));
  internal.forEach((item) => item.classList.add("internal"));

  const getLinks = () => {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    const internal = [...links]?.filter((item) => item.getAttribute("href")?.startsWith("/"));
    internal.forEach((item) => item.classList.add("internal"));
    console.log(internal, internal.length);
  };

  const recalculateInternal = () => {
    getLinks();
    internal.forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target);
      });
    });
  };

  recalculateInternal();

  const template = `
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/link4">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link5">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://some-site.com">Link 7</a></li>
    </ul>
    `;

  trigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", template);
    recalculateInternal();
  });
```

```html
 <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/another-link">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <p>Heading</p>
      <div>This is some article text with an <a href="/article-link">internal</a> link</div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div>
        <p>Section heading</p>
        <p>Another article with an <a href="https://google.co.uk">external</a> link</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <button class="add-template">Add template</button>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
```

When I trigger the event, the links dynamically added to the array of internal links are reflected in the console. But they do not appear to have the click event added dynamically. My guess is each time new dynamic links are added I need someway to remove them from all items with a forEach loop and add them again with the new links in the DOM.

[image]

I have researched adding and removing event handlers for an array of elements after using a forEach loop and I don't understand how to get anything to work. removeEventListener requires a listener name.

I tried to add `internal.forEach((item) => item.replaceWith(item.cloneNode(true)));`

Inside this function:

```
  trigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", template);
    internal.forEach((item) => item.replaceWith(item.cloneNode(true)));
    recalculateInternal();
  });
```

From what I understand that should remove all event handlers from those items. And they should be reinitialised again inside my `recalculateInternal` function.

For reference

[Javascript/DOM: How to remove all event listeners of a DOM object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-event-listeners-of-a-dom-object)

[removeEventListener without knowing the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845535/removeeventlistener-without-knowing-the-function)

Comment: Add the eventListener to the wrapper, test the  event.target.closest('a') to only target anchors and handle child elements. Done!

Comment: `wrapper.addEventListener("click", (event) => { const tgt = event.target.closest('a'); if (!tgt || !tgt.getAttribute("href")?.startsWith("/")) return; event.preventDefault();  tgt.classList.add('internal'); console.log(tgt);});`

Comment: Yeah thanks, It seems a much better option although it doesn't actually answer how to remove an event listener after binding it with a `forEach` loop. Thank you.

Comment: I did not answer that because it is not the solution. X/Y problem...

Comment: ^ that technique is known as Event Delegation

Comment: @mplungjan I am very grateful, and sorry I didn't mean to sound like I was ungrateful. It was just a general comment about answering JS question, but thank you. I am on the right path now :D

Comment: I was not offended in any way, I just wanted to tell you why I did not answer the specific question. [There are many answers here](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+event+handler+OR+listener+OR+eventListener+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com)