# List all javascript events wired up on a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Using jQuery, is it possible to get a list of all the events and to which element the event is bound to?

Comment: Take a look at <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675120/inspect-javascript-calls-for-gmails-buttons/677924#677924">this question</a> and <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681120/access-events-added-with-attachevent-addeventlistener-in-javascript">this one</a>.

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10589 .data('events') is gone now

Comment: Thanks, @SkylarSaveland, I am updating my answer below.

Answer (score 95):

jQuery makes this relatively easy because it stores the event handlers in the element data.  You should be able to use something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.eventReport = function(selector, root) {
        var s = [];
        $(selector || '*', root).andSelf().each(function() {
            // the following line is the only change
            var e = $.data(this, 'events');
            if(!e) return;
            s.push(this.tagName);
            if(this.id) s.push('#', this.id);
            if(this.className) s.push('.', this.className.replace(/ +/g, '.'));
            for(var p in e) {
                var r = e[p],
                    h = r.length - r.delegateCount;
                if(h)
                    s.push('\n', h, ' ', p, ' handler', h > 1 ? 's' : '');
                if(r.delegateCount) {
                    for(var q = 0; q < r.length; q++)
                        if(r[q].selector) s.push('\n', p, ' for ', r[q].selector);
                }
            }
            s.push('\n\n');
        });
        return s.join('');
    }
    $.fn.eventReport = function(selector) {
        return $.eventReport(selector, this);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and you can call it:

```
// all events
alert($.eventReport());

// just events on inputs
alert($.eventReport('input')); 

// just events assigned to this element
alert($.eventReport('#myelement')); 

// events assigned to inputs in this element
alert($.eventReport('input', '#myelement')); 
alert($('#myelement').eventReport('input')); // same result

// just events assigned to this element's children
alert($('#myelement').eventReport()); 
alert($.eventReport('*', '#myelement'); // same result
```

**UPDATE:**
I added a count of handlers and some information about delegated events to the output of the above function.

**UPDATE (8/24/2012):**
While the function above still works in jQuery 1.7.2 and lower, jQuery no longer stores the event object in `jQuery.data(elem, 'events')` and **if you are using jQuery 1.8 or later you will no longer be able to use the function above!**

In exchange for `jQuery.data(elem, 'events')` you can now use `jQuery._data(elem, 'events')`. An update to the function above would look like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.eventReport = function(selector, root) {
        var s = [];
        $(selector || '*', root).addBack().each(function() {
            // the following line is the only change
            var e = $._data(this, 'events');
            if(!e) return;
            s.push(this.tagName);
            if(this.id) s.push('#', this.id);
            if(this.className) s.push('.', this.className.replace(/ +/g, '.'));
            for(var p in e) {
                var r = e[p],
                    h = r.length - r.delegateCount;
                if(h)
                    s.push('\n', h, ' ', p, ' handler', h > 1 ? 's' : '');
                if(r.delegateCount) {
                    for(var q = 0; q < r.length; q++)
                        if(r[q].selector) s.push('\n', p, ' for ', r[q].selector);
                }
            }
            s.push('\n\n');
        });
        return s.join('');
    }
    $.fn.eventReport = function(selector) {
        return $.eventReport(selector, this);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE (4/25/2013):**
`andSelf()` is deprecated from 1.8.x http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9800 , I replaced with `addBack()` instead.

Comment: Updated with jQuery 1.8 fix and some additional output for handler count and delegated events.

Comment: Answer does not include events on the document or window, FYI, although you can get them doing $.eventReport(document) and $.eventReport(window)

Comment: I seem to keep coming back to this every few years, and it's still working. Such a fantastic tool to have.

Comment: This is going to my collection of super-cool and useful scripts.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the `var r = e[p]` array? I'm asking because it doesn't look like a "normal" array, but rather something else/native.

Comment: @alexandernst, it is not an array, but an object. You can modify it although I would do so carefully... it is part of jQuery's internals, used to manage events.

Answer (score 5):

```
// List bound events
console.log($('#elem').data('events'));

// Log ALL handlers for ALL events
$.each($('#elem').data('events'), function(i, event) {
  $.each(event, function(i, handler){
    console.log(handler.toString());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this one to list all elements that has a bounded event.

```
$('*').each(function(){
    var events = $(this).data('events');
    if(events != null)
    {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(events);
    }
});
```

It is also possible to collect elements as a list for each event by writing some additional codes like this:

```
var eventArrays = {};

$('*').each(function(){
    var events = $(this).data('events');
    for(var anEvent in events){
        if(!eventArrays[anEvent])
            eventArrays[anEvent] = [];
        eventArrays[anEvent].push(this);
    }
});

console.log(eventArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could traverse the DOM and inspect the event [attribute](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#name) on each element building up a list... but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

To use console.table() I did some modifications...

```
(function($) {
    $.eventReport = function(selector, root) {
        var s = [];
        $(selector || '*', root).addBack().each(function() {
            var e = $._data(this, 'events');
            if(!e) return;
            var tagGroup = this.tagName || "document";
            if(this.id) tagGroup += '#' + this.id;
            if(this.className) tagGroup += '.' + this.className.replace(/ +/g, '.');

            var delegates = [];
            for(var p in e) {
                var r = e[p];
                var h = r.length - r.delegateCount;

                if(h)
                    s.push([tagGroup, p + ' handler' + (h > 1 ? 's' : '')]);

                if(r.delegateCount) {
                    for(var q = 0; q < r.length; q++)
                        if(r[q].selector) s.push([tagGroup + ' delegates', p + ' for ' + r[q].selector]);
                }
            }
        });
        return s;
    }
    $.fn.eventReport = function(selector) {
        return $.eventReport(selector, this);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

So now I can do things like this:

```
console.table($.eventReport())
```

See what happens at chrome:
[image: Console in chrome]