# Is it possible enumerate all the page ready event observers, using jquery / js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to report all the observers of the 'ready' events. I have a page where something is happening twice, and i'm trying to chase it back to the source.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743876/list-all-javascript-events-wired-up-on-a-page-using-jquery

Comment: @marcgg - This is an entirely different question, the answers to the one marked as duplicate don't apply at all...it's a very special case in jQuery, not the general one the other question's asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this after it's executed, as it's a special event handler, which that "duplicate" question doesn't really cover.

[`$(document).ready(func)` (or `$(func)`)](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) or [stores the functions you want to call in `readyList`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L247) (internal array).  Unfortunately for your situation, but good for performance/garbage collection, this list is nulled out after it runs, so you can't get the list you're looking for.

[You can see how this happens in jQuery core here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L363).

Your best bet would be `console.log()` in a few functions /files to see if you get any duplicates I'd say.

Comment: in theory I could add code to my copy of core and log the contents of readylist....

Comment: @Adrian - That's another option, I'd suggest adding it before line 242 here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L247