# How can I reliably kill every jQuery event wired up, regardless of event type, handler or DOM element

Tags: jquery, performance-testing

Using the **fantastic** (yet cruelly not accepted) post on this question: [List all javascript events wired up on a page using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743876/list-all-javascript-events-wired-up-on-a-page-using-jquery) I have discovered that it's possible to query the **jQuery events cache** to read the events that are wired up, what they're wired up to and so on.

I also have Visual Event, a bookmarklet which overlays event bindings onto the actual HTML elements on screen.

What I need now - to test the impact of the events which are hooked up on my page, is to literally **unbind, kill, die (etc) every single event** which jQuery knows about - but this seems to be tricky to achieve without knowing all of the context (e.g. selector, handlers) - the reason is to test the "general" page performance, filling in forms, scrolling around, collapsing/expanding stuff and so on.

I can potentially 'roll my own' script to do this, using the script in the question I posted above to get all the items and then removing them - but I'm not sure if this is possible, or the best way to go around it - I hope that I'm re-inventing a pre-existing wheel by suggesting this.

What I really want/need is:

```
  $(document).removeAllEventsThatAreWiredUpToAnything();
```

...but I know it does not exist.

Is there an easy way to do this? **Disabling JavaScript is not really an option** as my pages are built fairly extensively with ajax calls that fire when loading up, so it wouldn't be that useful a test.

More than happy to take/accept solutions rather than direct answers - just need to gather some understanding of performance impact of event overuse in the **quickest** possible way.

Regards
-SB

Comment: Can you just prevent default to stop the event from bubbling. I don't know if that would work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$('*').unbind();
```

will unbind all event types for all elements.

Comment: Does this work for bind(), live() and delegate() ? Or just bind - I have very little which uses bind - it's a mixture (unfortunately) of delegate() and live()

Comment: You can use the [die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/) and [undelegate()](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) methods.

Comment: Works really well. I am gobsmacked that it was so simple, slightly embarassed that I couldn't find documentation about it particularly easily and also massively pleased with the simplicity!