# How to list events which were bind by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to list events which were bind by jQuery for an element? I tried the methods from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743876/list-all-javascript-events-wired-up-on-a-page-using-jquery) and none worked.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jam6L)

Answer (score 3):

The code you linked to does work, it's just that because you used `live()` (which is a [deprecated function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) from version 1.7 on), the handler is bound to the top level element, the `document`, and it uses event bubbling to figure out the original element and see if it matches your selector.

Because you tried to call the `$.eventReport()` for a specific selector, rather than `document`, nothing was returned.

If you change `live` to `on`, you will see that the alert does show something ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjafw/)). Alternatively, if you omit the selector to `$.eventReport()` altogether, you will also see that a click event is bound ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CDEwG/1/)).

Example for the former:

```
$(function() {
    $('#firstname').on("click", function(e) {
        alert('clicked');
    });

    alert($.eventReport('#firstname'));
});​
```

Comment: @elclanrs Yeah, you have to jump on these sorts of questions *so* quickly. Sorry you lost the race this time, my friend!

Comment: Thanks. Is there a tool or Firefox extension which does this without writing code?

Comment: My favourite cross browser solution is the [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) bookmarklet. It's pretty awesome, give it a try. Otherwise, Firebug and some of the Firebug extensions can give you this sort of information.