# Can an event be be triggered if that event is attached to an element that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, security, events

So, there are two important details to this question:

1. its inside the scope of document ready's callback function
2. **the element** that the event is attached to **does not actually exist in the DOM**

Here's a visual representation of the scenario

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myNonExistentElement').on('click', function() {
        //do something
    });
});
```

**Is it possible to programatically trigger that click event (via console or something else) under those circumstances?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simple answer is no.

There are two cases which might, however, fit with your question:

1) If you just want to execute the event handler code, use a named function (instead of an anonymous function) and call it whenever you need to.

2) If you want to bind a click handler to an object that does not yet exist in the DOM but you know will in the future, you can use code like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '#myNonExistentElement', function() {
    //do something
  });
});
```

See the section about delegated events at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

If you try to bind an event to an element that doesn't exist via jQuery (or at the very least, `.on`) no new event will be bound.

Sample case [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N54KW/2/).

*event code stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743876/list-all-javascript-events-wired-up-on-a-page-using-jquery) because I'm lazy.