# Is there a way to get a list of the currently addedtostage events in JavaScript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am wondering if there is a way to get a list of the currently `addedtostage` events in JavaScript without jQuery?

I want to know this because I want to remove these events later.

I looked around on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find an answer without jQuery.

I tried:

```
Event.observers.each(function(item) {
   if(item[0] == element) {
      console.log(item[2])
   }
});
```

I also looked at [List all javascript events wired up on a page using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743876/list-all-javascript-events-wired-up-on-a-page-using-jquery)

Comment: Nitpick: you probably mean all currently _registered_ event handlers.  Only one event handler can _run_ at a time, unless there is some multithreaded JavaScript implementation out there I don't know about. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know since eventListenerList haven't been included in DOM 3 there is still no way to actually do it natively in js.

if it's just for debuging you can use tool such as visual event (http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event ) which know how majors libs suscribe events and how to read in it.