# 'attacheventlistener' and 'onclick' prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Maybe there are serval sub-questions for my problem:

- Is there a general solution to get events binded to an element?(Without jquery or others javascript librarys).
- I found `$(element).data('events')` can't get event registered with `<element onclick="some_functions()">`. How can we get it?

My goal is to insert an event before native event (registered by the programmer of html page). I found two solutions.

- Using jQuery [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743876/list-all-javascript-events-wired-up-on-a-page-using-jquery)
- modify `HTMLElement.prototype.addeventlister` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

However, I find both these methods can't solve the situation like that

```
<element onclick="some_functions()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access (and overwrite) that event handler via the `onclick` property. If you have a

```
<span id="elem" onclick="some_functions()">
```

then `document.getElementById("elem").onclick` will yield the anonymous function

```
function (event) {
    some_functions()
}
```

To intercept it, you can use something like

```
var fn = elem.onclick;
elem.onclick = function() {
    console.log("before");
    var res = fn.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("after");
    return res;
};
```

Disclaimer: This might not in older browsers, I don't know how the inventors (Netscape, IE) of inline attribute event handlers and traditional event registration handled these. They might as well have done something like `eval(elem.getAttribute("onclick"))`, in any case you can access the handler code (as a string) like that.

Comment: For the first questions, can we get all events binded to one element using javascript only? Maybe not cross-browser, just for Chrome.

Comment: No, not programmatically from JS at least. You can inspect them in the dev tools, though. I thought you already had found that answer in the linked questions?