# Limits of JavaScript's eval (and jQuery's globalEval)

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I'm interested in knowing the limits of JavaScript's `eval` method.

```
eval("console.log('This is a test')");
```

will work as expected, printing the text `This is a test` in the browser's dev-console.
But what about this code:

```
eval("jQuery(window).on('load', function(){ console.log('This is a test'); });");
```

Would that cause the browser to print the text after the page is loaded?

What about using jQuery's `globalEval`? Would that make any difference?

Regards

EDIT: I'm doing some tests using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/745386/940158 
Even after `eval`ing the jQUery code, the handler doesn't show up when I do `$.eventReport(window)`, which makes me believe that `eval` is failing at some point.

Comment: _"Would that cause the browser to print the text after the page is loaded?"_ What's stopping you from trying?

Comment: @Cerbrus I tried and it doesn't, now I'm looking for an explication if it's possible and if not, why.

Comment: @alexandernst: Probably because you evaled that code after the `load` event did fire. Try using `jQuery(document).ready(` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`evil()` Literally (attempts to) run the code provided in it's parameter.
Any JavaScript that works, should work when wrapped in a string, in a `evil()`.

As long as `jQuery` exists at the moment you're calling the second line, the code should execute just fine. Even though the `load` event might have passed already, at that time.
(So, the event listener will be added, but might not fire)

Comment: I don't know enough about `globalEval` to answer that part of the question, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, I'm asking all this because I'm making some tests with http://stackoverflow.com/a/745386/940158 and even after eval-ing the jQuery code, the handler doesn't show up when I do `$.eventReport(window)`, which makes me think that `eval` is failing somewhere.

Comment: Why are you even `evil`-ing anything? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: I'm just curious about the limits of `eval` and I'm searching a reasonable answer about either why it works or why it doesn't work.

Comment: `evil` literally starts a new JavaScript interpreter, and has it interpret the passed string. It not working might not even be related to `evil`.

Comment: So you mean the context of `eval` is different when running code than the context that is already loaded? That doesn't make too much sense because I can call an already loaded function from `eval`, like this: `eval("my_function();")`.

Comment: I just mean it literally starts a new interpreter (--> Horribly inefficient). Code in the `evil` still has access to the scope "outside" of it.

Comment: Ok, so it should work, but it doesn't. Now I'd like to know *why* it doesn't work. "It starts a new interpreter" is not a valid answer as I already demonstrated that the new interpreter shares the same context.

Comment: Replace the `.on('load'` with `.on('click'`, see if that works.
Better yet, add a normal `onload` with a `console.log`, and check if the `evil` is executed before or after the `onload` event fires. My guess is that it doesn't work, simply because the event's passed already.

Comment: I understand your concern about the event being already fired, really. The question is that even after manually checking *what* events are binded to the `window` object (with the link I posted a few replies earlier), there are *no* handlers at all, which means that the `eval` failed.

Comment: So, are you certain `jQuery` exists, when call the `evil`?